# Loop with timeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to find ways to make my function more dynamic with the loop. I understand how one can simplify by using onclick event listener. But since I am calling using ajax, it's quite confusing. I figure it will be really messy if I were to input 3 setTimeout in the function.

```
 const eventHandler = function(){reverse.click(function(){
               setTimeout(function(){
                 updateDATA();
                 $("#" + arcapi.chartId() + " tbody td .crosstab-collapse").click(function(){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                     updateDATA();
                    },0);
                 })
               },0)
            })
          }
      eventHandler()
```

Note: It's required to load dom first before and select element within the timeout as DOM is overwrite with new element.
I thought of creating a function which one can input number of times it will run, for an example

```
function setFunc(number){

for(let i = 1 ; i < number; i++){
   onst eventHandler = function(){reverse.click(function(){
               setTimeout(function(){
                 updateDATA();

               },0)
            })
          }
     }

setFunc(3)
```

is it possible to achieve this?

**UPDATED**

What i am trying to achieve is whenever the user click, JS will need to recapture dom elements again. refer the pseudo code below

```
// User will click
 $("#" + arcapi.chartId() + " tbody td .crosstab-collapse").click(function(){
//After table is refresh after ajax call, new dom will overwrite, need timer
        setTimeout(function(){
                  console.log($("#" + arcapi.chartId() + " tbody td .crosstab-collapse"))
        },0)
      })
```

// Will need restart the code once user click the button again as DOM will always be overwritten with new DOM elements.

**Conclusion**
i solved the issue by appending a function within a function, every time function fire, it will keep calling the same button

```
 function reverseData(){
      $("#" + arcapi.chartId() + " tbody td .crosstab-collapse").click(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
                  updateDATA()
                  reverseData()
        },0)
      })  
    }

      //main rever event handler , initial load 
        $("#" + arcapi.chartId() + " tbody td .crosstab-collapse").click(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                  updateDATA()
                  reverseData()
            },0)
        })
```

Comment: can you describe what should happen exactly, what the user does, and what the result should be?

Comment: @WesleySmith, ive updated the question. I needed to create a loop. if everytime user click button , when user want to click button again. it will have to overwrite old DOM elements with new one

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you.

```js
function eventHandler() {
  var tr = [1, 2, 3];
  setTimeout(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      var time = 1000 * (i + 1);
      setFunc(time);
    }
  }, 100);
}

function setFunc(time) {

  setTimeout(function() {
    ///updateDATA();
    console.log(time);
  }, time);

}
eventHandler();
```